# Cloud Functions for Firebase - GeoFire implementation

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, geofire

Implementing GeoFire as follow:

```
const GeoFire = require('geofire');
const geoFire = new GeoFire(admin.database().ref().child('geolocation'));
```

In database onWrite:

```
const promises = [];
promises.push(geoFire.set(id, [37.79, -122.41]));
return Promise.all(promises);
```

In the code below I do a geoquery:

```
exports.nearbyjobs = functions.database.ref('/users/{userid}/account/l').onWrite(event => {
  const location = event.data;
  if (location.child("lat").val() === null || location.child("lng").val() === null) return;
  const key = event.data.key;
  const uid = event.params.userid;
  const results = geoFire.query({
    center: [location.child("lat").val(), location.child("lng").val()],
    radius: 3000
  });
});
```

My question and problem is how de I handle the `results` from geofire query? I need to have the query result in my DB updating in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
var arr = [];
var onKeyEnteredRegistration = results.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
      console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
//each location is added to the array
      arr.push[{'key':key, 'location':location, 'distance':distance}];
    });
```

Good luck.